# 414.shtml error while updating the blog with increased content size

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE4Zx.png]
While creating the post there is no problem, i can go upto 10000 characters also.

But while editing the same post it has some limit and it goes to error page.

Comment: Image of error as above ys

Comment: Hello, please put some of your code. Now 414 indicates that you are most likely using a GET request while you should use a POST request. 
**FYI**: you are hitting an error page from your server rather than Laravel

Comment: Hi @ChristopheHubert , Which code you would like to refer to.

Comment: Please share your blade, route and Controller